# Flutter Firestore add new document with Custom ID

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to add new document with custom id using Dart and Flutter?

> PS: I can add new document to collection but its id sets randomly, using this code
>
> `postRef.add(data);`
>
> which `postRef` is `CollectionReference` and `data` is `Map<String, dynamic>`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `set()` function instead of `add()`.

Here's full code:

```
final CollectionReference postsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('/posts');

var postID = 1;

Post post = new Post(postID, "title", "content");
Map<String, dynamic> postData = post.toJson();
await postsRef.doc(postID).set(postData);
```

I hope that help anyone.

Comment: Is it possible to create autoID?

Comment: Yes sure, you can use `await postsRef.add(postData);` that was the question really !

Comment: from where do we bring '.toJson();' ?? it's not defined and would be cool instead of what i'm doing not is I take every class like Post() and map its fields into a map,,

if .toJson(); work automatically would be cool,, from where can I import that ? or I just define that function like I'm already doing ?

Comment: @RagehElAzzazy it's a method I defined in tge class, to return a map with keys an fields I want. No difference between my code and your code, just it's a method in class.

Comment: @Shady Boshra, I did the same, thanks man, teslam ya m3allem

Comment: @Bagusflyer If you dont provide doc() a parameter, then its generates an auto-ID

Answer (score 10):

#### Update 2021:

Instead of using `add`, use `set` on the document.

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
collection 
    .doc('doc_id') // <-- Document ID
    .set({'age': 20}) // <-- Your data
    .then((_) => print('Added'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Add failed: $error'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String uniqueCode = //Your Unique Code
DocumentReference reference = Firestore.instance.document("test/" + uniqueCode );

//Setting Data
Map<String, String> yourData;
reference.setData(yourData);
```

Comment: This works too but If its a shared database I would recommend handling the atomicity by making each transaction atomic as follows ```Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
            await _firestoreRef.setData(data);
          }); ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to insert new Document with customID

```
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> users = FirebaseFirestore
              .instance
              .collection('/users')
              .doc("MyCustomID");
          var myJSONObj = {
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Doe",
          };
          users
              .set(myJSONObj)
              .then((value) => print("User with CustomID added"))
              .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
```